# Python import iteration, sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sys

So I was wondering, at this point in time I'm reading a book about Python. The book explains the following:

> The import algorithm
>
> To truly understand namespace packages, we have
>   to look under the hood to see how the `import` operation works in 3.3.
>   During imports, Python still iterates over each directory in the
>   module search path, `sys.path`, just as in 3.2 and earlier.

My question is: How is python able to iterate through `sys.path` when sys is not imported. Also if python is able to see `sys` without import to iterate through `sys.path` why  do we need to import `sys` in our code?

```
>>> sys
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined.

>>> import sys
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no contradiction. Python's `sys` module *exposes* the search path configurations that modifies the behaviour of `import` to the Python side, but even without importing `sys` in your Python code, the interpreter knows about its own configurations.

In the following [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/pathconfig.c#L18) it is commented that

```
/* _PyMem_SetDefaultAllocator() is needed to get a known memory allocator,
   since Py_SetPath(), Py_SetPythonHome() and Py_SetProgramName() can be
   called before Py_Initialize() which can changes the memory allocator. */
```

What this means is that [`Py_SetPath()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath), which is responsible for setting the module search path, can be executed so early, before any Python code can be interpreted (for example, `import` statements), that it needs its own memory allocator before the interpreter's own memory allocator takes over.

By the time Python interpreter's `main()` function is run, [it can already read](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/main.c#L2069) the path configuration using [`Py_GetPath()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/pathconfig.c#L208) that calls the internal function [`_PyPathConfig_Init()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/pathconfig.c#L49) if necessary, which is safe to do even before the interpreter is ready to execute Python code.